# Serialize multiple classes to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class, encoder

I have a class A where it stores a collection of variables of type B, how can I serialize class A to JSON properly?

example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_collection = []
    #...

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

and add instances of `B` into the collection:

```
a = A()
a.b_collection = [B(), B(), B()]
```

when I try to serialize `a` with `json.dumps(a)` I get this error: `Object of type A is not JSON serializable`.

Is there a way to specify how to encoder should encode that class?

something like

```
def __encode__(self, encoder):
    encoder.start_obj()
    encoder.add_property('name', self.value)
    encoder.add_property('age', self.age)
    encoder.end_obj()
```

which would return something like

```
{
   name: 'Tomer',
   age: '19'
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to serialize `a`, `json.dumps(a)`?

Comment: @chepner yes, sorry forgot to mention it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `json.JSONEncoder` to define how to serialize your objects. The `default` method of your subclass will take a Python object as an argument. You can return a new object that is (hopefully) encodable, or pass the object on to the parent in hopes that it knows how to encode the object.

For example,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_collection = []

class B:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class ABEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, A):
            return {'__A__': obj.b_collection}
        elif isinstance(obj, B):
            return {'__B__': obj.__dict__}
        return super().default(obj)


a = A()
a.b_collection.append(B("Tomer", "19"))
a.b_collection.append(B("Bob", "21"))
a.b_collection.append(B("Alice", "23"))
print(json.dumps(a, cls=ABEncoder, indent=4))
```

would produce

```
{
    "__A__": [
        {
            "__B__": {
                "name": "Tomer",
                "age": "19"
            }
        },
        {
            "__B__": {
                "name": "Bob",
                "age": "21"
            }
        },
        {
            "__B__": {
                "name": "Alice",
                "age": "23"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you can handle `A` and `B` separately; you don't have to first encode the `B` objects before returning the encodable form of `A`; the `B` objects will be encoded later when the list itself is encoded.

The extra objects make it easier to write a decoder; you don't have to make it this complicated if you don't want to be able to decode the JSON to an instance of `A`. Instead, you can just define

```
class ABEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, A):
            return obj.b_collection
        elif isinstance(obj, B):
            return obj.__dict__
        return super().default(obj)
```

to get

```
[
    {
        "name": "Tomer",
        "age": "19"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": "21"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": "23"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data classes can help:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from typing import List
import json


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: str


@dataclass
class Group:
    persons: List[Person]


data = [
    {'name': 'Tomer', 'age': '19'},
    {'name': 'Ivan', 'age': '20'}
]
persons = [Person(**person) for person in data]

group = Group(persons=persons)
assert json.dumps(asdict(group)) == '{"persons": [{"name": "Tomer", "age": "19"}, {"name": "Ivan", "age": "20"}]}'

persons = [asdict(person) for person in group.persons]
assert persons == [{"name": "Tomer", "age": "19"}, {"name": "Ivan", "age": "20"}]
assert json.dumps(persons) == '[{"name": "Tomer", "age": "19"}, {"name": "Ivan", "age": "20"}]'
```